# How do I send a range to comment?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a master graph which tells me how many total hard drives I have in stock between front stock, and back stock. It pulls info which is broken down all the way down to part number. One thing I found is that I have totals of each size/form on my master graph, totals of each brand in front stock, totals of each brand in back stock, but not a total of each brand across the board.

Now, I would like to have it so I can see almost everything I need to know from the main graph page. What I would like to do is hover over a size in the center column (N), and it displays an image/range which shows the totals of each brand for that size. I have tried macros, searched, everything. Nothing I've found will work.

Here are some screen shots of what i have so far.
[image: Master Graph]
[image: Page with totals]

I know I'm going to be told you guys are not code writers and that i need to post an example, well i don't have anything that would remotely work.

Comment: Maybe a PIVOT TABLE would do what you want?

Comment: I have never setup a pivot table before. When i get home from work, i'll give it a try and see were it leads me. Thank you for the advice @Raystafarian